# How to Update one form data to different tables in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am working with Laravel 5.6 and MySQL. in My app I have some data edit form and its updated values saving with 3 different tables. called vehicles, cars and upload My edit form url as following,

```
http://localhost:8000/myads/1/edit
```

number (1) is vehicle table id number, like this,

```
id    name         owner  
1     toyota        dane
2     BMW           peter
3     Benz          samantha
4     volvo         Alex
```

and car table is like this,

```
id     fuel    vehicle_id
1       P              1
2       D              3
3       E              2
```

I need update cars table data with regarding to vehicle_id , My VehicleController vehicle table data update function is like this

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $vehicle = Vehicle::find($id);

        $vehicle->name = $request->input('name');
        $vehicle->owner = $request->input('owner');

        $vehicle->save();
}
```

now I need update cars table fuel values with same form optional values input. how can I do this in the Controller?

My fuel selection input is like this,

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Fuel</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="fuel" name="fuel">
            @foreach($vehicles->cars as $car)
            <option value="{!! $car->fuel  !!}">{!! $car->fuel  !!}</option>
            @endforeach 
        <option value="P">Petrol</option>
        <option value="D">Diesel</option>
        <option value="H">Hybrid</option>
        <option value="E">Electric</option>

        </select>
        </div>
```

**relationship among Vehicle and Car Models are**

Vehicle Model

```
public function cars()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Car::class);
    }
```

Car Model

```
public function vehicle()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vehicle::class);
    }
```

How can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden Input field (load car id to the input using $car->id ) in form and name it as 'car_id'. 
In the same update function,

```
 $carId = $request->input('car_id');
 $car= Car::find($carId);
 //Update details here
 $car->save();
```

Note : when you are working with multiple table, do not forget to use DB Transaction.

Answer (score 0):

got success with following codes,

```
$vehicle->cars()->where('vehicle_id', $id)->update(['fuel' => $request->input('fuel')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the fuel values of the cars table for a specific vehicle, you can add the following code inside the `update` function of the `VehicleController`:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $vehicle = Vehicle::find($id);

    $vehicle->name = $request->input('name');
    $vehicle->owner = $request->input('owner');

    $vehicle->save();

    // Update fuel values of cars table
    foreach ($vehicle->cars as $car) {
        if ($car->fuel != $request->input('fuel')) {
            $car->fuel = $request->input('fuel');
            $car->save();
        }
    }
}
```

To take input from the user, you can use HTML form elements in your view file. For example, to take input for the vehicle name and owner, you can use the following code:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('vehicles.update', $vehicle->id) }}">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" value="{{ $vehicle->name }}" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="owner">Owner</label>
        <input type="text" name="owner" id="owner" class="form-control" value="{{ $vehicle->owner }}" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fuel">Fuel</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="fuel" name="fuel">
            <option value="P" {{ $vehicle->cars->where('fuel', 'P')->count() ? 'selected' : '' }}>Petrol</option>
            <option value="D" {{ $vehicle->cars->where('fuel', 'D')->count() ? 'selected' : '' }}>Diesel</option>
            <option value="H" {{ $vehicle->cars->where('fuel', 'H')->count() ? 'selected' : '' }}>Hybrid</option>
            <option value="E" {{ $vehicle->cars->where('fuel', 'E')->count() ? 'selected' : '' }}>Electric</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```